# how to read a file thats comma‐delimited

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner, split

im tring to read from a file with a list of strings. there are three lines in the file and im trying to print them as they look in the file but the output only prints the first line. 'woman' should not be printed. nor should 'man'

```
   public void readFile(String fileName) {
    String gender;
    String width;
    String height;
    String name;
    String x;
    String y;

     try {
        scanIn = new Scanner (new File (fileName));
        this.scanIn.useDelimiter(", ");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NumberFormatException exception) {

        exception.getMessage();
    }

    while(this.scanIn.hasNext()){
        gender = scanIn.next();

        if(gender.equals("woman")){

            width = scanIn.next();
            height = scanIn.next();
            x = scanIn.next();
            y = scanIn.next();
            name = scanIn.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s", width,height,x,y,name);
        }
         if(gender.equals("man")){

                width = scanIn.next();
                height = scanIn.next();
                x = scanIn.next();
                y = scanIn.next();
                name = scanIn.next();

                System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s", width,height,x,y,name);

            }
    }
}
```

the file looks like

```
man, 20, 15, 55, 90, phil
woman, 30, 10, 5, 80, Sam
man, 320, 170, 10, 90, olie
```

the output should be

```
20, 15, 55, 90, phil
30, 10, 5, 80, Sam
320, 170, 10, 90, olie
```

instead the output gives me

```
20, 15, 55, 90, phil
woman
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because when you use the delimiter to be `", "`, the scanner won't stop when it encounters a new line.

So, when it reads the first line, it will read `phil\nwomen` as a single token. So your loop will get messed up.

To Fix, you can tell it to delimit on `", |\n"`, which will also delmit on new line characters.

```
scanIn.useDelimiter(", |\n");
```

**Note:** You may also want to add a **newline** at the end of your `printf()` statements, or you will get the whole output in a single line.